# Ordinary-Differential-Equation, elimination method

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Solve the following ODE with elimination:$$\dot u = u - v$$$$\dot v = u + v $$

$$\implies u''=u'-v'=-2v $$ and $$\implies v''=u'+v'=2u $$ it follows:
$$4u=-u^{(4)}$$$$4v=-v^{(4)}$$
I find no solution for that.

Comment: "I find no solution for that." What about $u(t)=e^t\cos t$, say?

Answer (score 2):

You have two [linear homogeneous differential equations with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equations_with_constant_coefficients). Using the method described, you obtain the equation
\begin{equation}
z^4 = - 4,
\end{equation}
which should be straightforward to solve. Any linear combination of the solutions of the form $e^{z\, t}$ solves your problem.